# What is the physics behind lifting a submerged bucket out of water?

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics, bernoulli-equation

When you submerge a cylindrical bucket into the water and let all the air out, trying to lift the bucket back out is particularly difficult if we keep it vertical to the surface. In order for the water to drain out, air must push into the cylinder through the edges, Why doesn't this happen?Also, at what height would the force (gravity) be so great that it would vaporise the water? (of course supposing a situation where air doesn't seep in through the sides)

The bernoulli equation should apply here, we can see that the pressure decreases below atmospheric as the bucket rises

Comment: Bernoulli equation is for flowing fluid, not for approximately stationary fluid in a container, so it shouldn't apply here.

Comment: The force is due to the weight of the water column you lift.

Comment: It works for a stationary fluid? I would imagine it's stationary

Comment: Moreover for all heights I expect an equilibrium process to start, creating vapor, see [vapor pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapour_pressure_of_water). Only that it should go faster for lower pressures i.e. higher columns. From that point of view there is no critical height.

Comment: oh, for some reason i began to think it was because of air pressure. The air pushes down on the bucket with extra pressure $pgh$ because the pressure of the water decrease due to an increase in height. The pressure at the bottom of the bucket at the surface is atmospheric because it must be the same at any depth for equilibrium. And the pressure decreases up the bucket due to decreasing weight of water above. But how does the water in the bucket 'know' to push with atmospheric pressure?

Comment: mathematically that's probably correct, but i want to understand the physics interms of what happens to the particles. Also im curious, does air pressure increase as it tries to push in through the sides?

Comment: @rpfphysics It works for _flowing_ fluid.  It doesn't work for stationary.

Comment: mikuszefski, that suggests that at room temperature, water vapour needs to be around 133 Pa which is about 0 compared to 100kPa. so supposing the area of the bucket is 3.14, and the density of water is 1000, the height is 100/3.14 = 33m, is that about right/

Comment: but it also includes hydrostatic pressure, i think it works for any non turbulent incompressible fluid